# Redirect to Login page or give 403 error based on requested URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an app made with Spring boot using security. This app use MVC to show some pages and also use some rest interfaces for update/get objects.

Right now, every request I make without being logged in, i'm redirected to the **/login** page.

That's working as intented when I try to access from the web browser. But I want the app to react different when I try to access some particular path from the page, for example "/api/customers".

If I try to access to that path, I want to drop HTTP 403 error, not redirect to the login page.

This is my Security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.headers()
            .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.SAME_ORIGIN);

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/js/**", "/img/**")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logged-out")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")

    ;
}
```

Is this posible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#auth-entry-point

> The AuthenticationEntryPoint will be called if the user requests a
>   secure HTTP resource but they are not authenticated. An appropriate
>   AuthenticationException or AccessDeniedException will be thrown by a
>   security interceptor further down the call stack, triggering the
>   commence method on the entry point. This does the job of presenting
>   the appropriate response to the user so that authentication can begin.

```
@Component
public class Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
                               AuthenticationException ex)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        boolean somePath = request.getServletPath().equals("/somePath");

        if(somePath){
            response.sendError(SC_FORBIDDEN, "Access Denied");
        }
        else{
            response.sendRedirect("/login");
        }
    }
}
```

and register it with the Framework:

```
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security has a `DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint` that allows selection of a concrete `AuthenticationEntryPoint` based on a `RequestMatcher` evaluation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.7.x/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.html